Long running background thread terminated in ASP.NET
I've built an ASP.NET MVC web server that connects to a hardware device via a socket. The idea is to spawn a thread that opens a socket and listens for TCP packages from the hardware. Since the hardware performs a long-running task that takes a significant amount of time to complete (years), I want to keep the thread alive as long as possible to monitor the process using SignalR and save some data to the database.
To achieve this, I've created a thread as follows:
rs = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT_DATA_NUMBER());
rs.Start();  
Thread thread = new Thread(() => ListenerHandleConnections(rs));  
thread.IsBackground = true;  
thread.Start();

The thread workflow is as follows:
public static void ListenerHandleConnections(TcpListener listener)
{
     try
     {
         TcpClient client;
         while (true)
         {
             try
             {
                 client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                 //extract data and doing some task
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 //Doing some task
             }
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         //Doing some task
      }
}

The problem I'm facing is that when I deploy this to IIS and run it for more than 2 hours, the thread is killed, and no process is listening to the hardware anymore. Is this issue caused by IIS, and are there any solutions to fix it?
I've saved the exception to the database, and all I got is "Thread was being aborted."

IIS does have settings for stopping unused applications. You can turn it off and it might help here. But in general it’s not a great idea to use a web application for this kind of a thing since it may get recycled in some cases and needs to be started again with a request.

@SamiKuhmonen ty for the information, I'll try it. For further, I'll try to change it to Windows Services. But I don't know if it is safe to spawn a thread like that, I have seen QueueBackgroundWorkItem, and it seem like a better approach

Please use a Windows service app, and don't bother ASP.NET, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a

The issue you're facing is probably related to how IIS handles application pools and worker processes. IIS recycles application pools periodically, which can cause background threads to be terminated. This is why your long-running thread is being killed after a certain period of time.
You can adjust the application pool settings in IIS to prevent it from recycling.

Increase the Idle Timeout:
Go to the application pool settings in IIS and increase the idle timeout to a larger value or set it to 0 to disable it.

Disable Regular Recycling:
In the application pool's advanced settings, set the "Regular Time Interval" for recycling to a very high value or disable it.


